# how to change Oracle TNSlistiner path

Tags: oracle

hi
how to change this path: F:\app\MyLAP\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN\TNSLSNR

to this path: d:\app\MyLAP\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN\TNSLSNR

in the service ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question you want to change the path of the executable for the service. If that's rigth you should change `ImagePath` attribute value in the following registry branch: `HKLM->System->CurrentControlSet->Services->ServiceName`.

But if you have two different oracle DBs (on disk d:/ and disk f:/) you'd rather have two different services and you can switch listeners just by stopping one and starting another service.

Comment: thank's it works !!  how to delete SID name from the computer (ORCL)